# Replacing every 10th pipe with new line in unix

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, awk

Lets say I have fields:

```
name, number, id
```

I have a data file:

```
name1|number1|id1|name2|number2|id2...etc
```

I want to replace every 3rd pipe with a new line or '\n' so I get:

```
name1|number1|id1  
name2|number2|id2
```

I'm having no luck with awk or sed.

I've tried the following, and variations of:

```
awk '/"\|"/{c++;if(c==10){sub("\|","\n");c=0}}1' inputfile.txt  
sed 's/"|"/"\n"/2' inputfile.txt
```

It tells me awk:

> syntax error near line 1
>
> awk: illegal statement near line 1
>
> awk: syntax error near line 1
>
> awk: bailing out near line 1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example use this:

```
$ awk -v RS="|" '{printf $0 (NR%3?RS:"\n")}' file
name1|number1|id1
name2|number2|id2..
```

#### Explanation

- `-v RS="|"` sets the record separator as `|`.
- `printf $0 (NR%3?RS:"\n")` print the full line with a new line in case the number of record is multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` answer. Not as elegant as the `awk` solution, but may come in handy:

```
i=3; IFS='|'; while read -a line; do echo "${line[*]:0:$i}"; echo "${line[*]:$i}"; done < inputfile.txt
```

Explanation:

- `i=3` Set this to the number of fields you want per line.
- `IFS='|'` Sets the delimiter to pipe.
- `while read -a line` Read each line from the input file into a bash array.
- `echo "${line[*]:0:$i}"` Print the first `$i` values of the array on a line.
- `echo "${line[*]:$i}"` Print the rest of the array on a line.